# How to create Android ViewModel that gets params?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm trying to create the VM class that gets int number as a param, following the updated instruction from the official website:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories

For example:

```
public class TargetFragmentVM extends ViewModel {
    private int targetId;

    public TargetFragmentVM(int targetId) {
        this.targetId = targetId;
    }

}
```

Here is an example from the official website for :

```
imports**
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public MyViewModel(
        MyRepository myRepository,
        SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle
    ) { /* Init ViewModel here */ }

    static final ViewModelInitializer<MyViewModel> initializer = new ViewModelInitializer<>(
        MyViewModel.class,
        creationExtras -> {
            MyApplication app = (MyApplication) creationExtras.get(APPLICATION_KEY);
            assert app != null;
            SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle = createSavedStateHandle(creationExtras);

            return new MyViewModel(app.getMyRepository(), savedStateHandle);
        }
    );
}

---

MyViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(
    this,
    ViewModelProvider.Factory.from(MyViewModel.initializer)
).get(MyViewModel.class);

// Rest of Activity code
}
```

But i can't understend how can i use it for my example, how can i pass just some int number as a parametr in this case.
?

Comment: I think VM is for most people a Virtual Machine not a View Model, so I have corrected your title to avoid congusion like I had after reading your question.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can be used to create a view-model with a constructor expecting an int parameter:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory = object : Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return if (TargetFragmentVM::class.java.isAssignableFrom(modelClass)) {
                try {
                    modelClass.getConstructor(Int::class.java).newInstance(id)
                } catch (e: NoSuchMethodException) {
                    throw RuntimeException("Cannot create an instance of $modelClass", e)
                } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
                    throw RuntimeException("Cannot create an instance of $modelClass", e)
                } catch (e: InstantiationException) {
                    throw RuntimeException("Cannot create an instance of $modelClass", e)
                } catch (e: InvocationTargetException) {
                    throw RuntimeException("Cannot create an instance of $modelClass", e)
                }
            } else super.create(modelClass)
        }
    })[TargetFragmentVM::class.java];
```

You can use a custom view-model factory and override it's create method to handle the creation logic by yourself. Then, through reflection, since the constructor expects an integer parameter, you can pass the integer to it (You can save it somewhere in your fragment/activity). This is similar to how pre-defined view-model factories work to create view-models under the hood (You can check ViewModelProvider.kt for reference). Hope this helps.